# Need help understanding syntax of Ruby on Rails controller and model inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So far when learning Ruby and Ruby on Rails I keep encountering the syntax

```
ActionController::Base
```

And have never clarified exactly what it means. Why the :: instead of say, a slash? Wouldn't ActionController/Base be more specific?

For example, while using the Globalize3 gem I added to my model the line

```
class About < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :message
end
```

I get the generated model named MonthlyPost::Translation, but that doesn't explain much. Where exactly are these stored, and what does the :: mean? Any thoughts would be wonderful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActionController::Base means find the class Base in the module ActionController.

It's a way of organising your classes, and also to avoid conflicts with classes made by others.

[Here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html) is a good article explaining how to use Modules for namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is ruby.  [Learn ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/) and your questions will be answered.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely agree. I'm currently reading the pickaxe ruby book, its a lot to learn so I try to ask more about certain topics im struggling with.